# Subscribe to a post's comments without posting a comment yourself

Tags: comments, email, notifications, subscription

I've seen a few plugins (subscribe2, subscribe to comments) that allow people that have commented to receive emails containing follow up comments.

What I want to do is slightly different.  I want to post to have a 'Subscribe' button.  Clicking this would then allow the user to receive by email subsequent comments to that post. They would not need to post a comment themselves.

Is this possible with a plugin, code or a mix of the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Subscribe To Comments Reloaded](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/) allows subscribing without commenting. It uses a link instead of a button, though.

Screen shot:

> [image]

It shouldn't be too hard to customize.

Comment: You're welcome! @toscho, thank you for fixing the image